# Win32: How to get window from DC (the reverse of GetDC)

Tags: winapi, gdi

Is there a way to get a window handle to the window owning a win32 DC? Or any other sort of information that might be useful for identifying the window, like DC width and height?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Coincidentally, there is [WindowFromDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145201(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: And to think, people are always complaining about the Windows API... :-)

Comment: Well, maybe it should be listed in the same group of functions as GetDC :) Or even be mentioned on the GetDC page :-p